# How to forward particular requests to https in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I have configured Nginx in this way:

```
#/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        listen [::]:8081 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name localhost;

        listen 443 ssl;

        location /site/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/;
        }

        # 404 occured
        #location /site/secure/ {
        #    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8081/site/secure/ https://localhost/site/secure/;
        #}


        location / {
            root /srv;
            index index.html index.htm;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

}
```

I have enabled https.
I have several urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/site/secure/
http://127.0.0.1:8081/sute/path1/...
http://127.0.0.1:8081/sute/path2/...
```

I want to redirect only `http://127.0.0.1:8081/site/secure/*` requests to `https://127.0.0.1/site/secure/*` so that user can't use this url with simple http.

But when I run Nginx with this redirect:

```
location /site/secure/ {
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8081/site/secure/ https://localhost/site/secure/;
}
```

I get 404 response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I configure nginx to redirect some request to https in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proxy_redirect` is the wrong directive. You need to use something like `return 301 https://...` to move the client from `http` to `https`.

The cleanest approach is to use two `server` blocks, and pull in common configuration statements with an `include` directive. For example:

```
server {
    listen 8081 default_server;
    listen [::]:8081 default_server ipv6only=on;

    include /path/to/common/bits;

    location ^~ /site/secure/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    include /path/to/common/bits;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But I have [read](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/nginx/3631/useful-redirects/12493/https-redirect#t=201702201618433467434) that it is better to return 307 status code because it preserves request type.

Comment: A valid consideration. But it also depends on the application. You might want a POST to http to fail horribly to avoid masking a serious bug.

Comment: I have issue while implementing current solution. When I send request to `/site/secure/` over http I have request header `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8`. But when it is redirected to https request doesn't have `Content-Type`, so I get error from server. Do you know how to preserve `Content-Type` during redirection to https? Thank you for response.